# Doubly LinkedList -- Getting a infinity link while printing though node is being updated

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I am not getting where I am wrong though the temp is updated to next everytime output is running to infinity
Note:
**THE CODE RUNS SUCCESSFULLY IF I ADD NODES GREATER THAN 2**
Need explaination why so..?

```
public class Basics {
    static class Node {
        int data ;
        Node next;
        Node prev;

        public Node(int data){
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
            this.prev = null;
        }
    }
    public static Node head;
    public static Node tail;
    public static int size;

    public void addFirst(int data){
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        if(head ==null){
            head =tail = newNode;
        }
        newNode.next = head;
        head.prev = newNode;
        head = newNode;
    }
    public void addLast(int data){
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        if(head ==null){
            head = tail = newNode;
            return;
        }
        tail.next = newNode;
        newNode.prev = tail;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    public void print(){
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp != null){
            System.out.print(temp.data +"<-->");
           temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println("null");
    }
    public void removeLast(){
        if(head ==null){
            System.out.println("The dll is already empty");
        }
        if(head.next == null){
            head = tail = null;
        }
        tail = tail.prev;
        tail.next = null;
    }
    public void removeFirst(){
        if(head.next == null){
            head = null;
        }
        head = head.next;
        head.prev = null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Basics dll = new Basics();
        dll.addFirst(8);
        dll.addFirst(343);
        dll.print();
        dll.removeFirst();
        dll.print();
    }
}`
```

Current output:
infinity connections of only with the value 8(data of the last node)

Comment: In `addFirst` you need a `return` inside the `if (head == null)`.

Comment: The code needs to check if `head == null` in the `removeFirst` function, just like it does in `removeLast`.